# Sourcetree error : 'git status' failed with code -1073741819

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Started getting following error in Sourcetree suddenly. I dont know what is the reason behind it. but I am nit able to resolve it.

Not able to perform any operation.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well. I followed the steps here and it solved my problem:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-2018

Specifically:

> Using the terminal and changing your directory to your repository you can do the following (making sure you back up your repository first, just in case):

`rm .git/index
git add .`

> Or if you have changes in your working directory you want to keep you can do the following:

`rm .git/index
git reset HEAD .`

Comment: This helped me; when I ran `git add .` it gave me this more useful error than SourceTree's error code: `fatal: bad config line 6 in file C:/Users/[user name]/.gitconfig`.  There was an error in my `.gitconfig` file (which I'd introduced myself) and was then able to fix.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it was not fixed even if I deleted the .git/index and .git/index.lock file.
I had to go to SourceTree Options -> Git and select "Use Embedded Git" to make it work. Before it was "Use System Git".

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Git was installed and then SourceTree with Git inside.
This generated a conflict between the two installed GITs.
You need to uninstall Git or in the SourceTree installation point where it is installed.

Comment: Are you able to provide a more detailed instruction / how to on your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Uninstall Git (Windows Start-> Control Panel-> Uninstall a program-> Git <Click Uninstall>) and after that install SourceTree with Git inside.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing with the same issue. My software configuration is:

- Windows 10
- SourceTree 2.0.18.1 configured to use System Git version
- Git v2.12.2.windows.1

> I updated Git to v2.12.2.windows.2 (the latest build) and the problem
>   disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

1. close Sourcetree window
2. open Sourcetree Bookmarks view
3. delete bookmark
4. add bookmark again